# Website using facebooklogin plugin and store user crenditials to database JAVA or Javascript into the textbox of my form

Tags: java, javascript, facebook

I am using Facebook Login Button to integrate with facebook in my website. But, I don't know how to save the username etc(userdata on facebook) from facebook to my database on login through facebook . How this can be done ?

Currently, when clicking the facebook login button an window is opened, we can enter the facebook username and password and it will be connected.

How to enter into JAVA or JAVASCRIPT part while login to store user datas on facebook and if already exist login to site without store any data ?

Also I want to store the data into my personal database of the User?Can it be done on Servlets?

I even made form now I want to extract the user's information and display it on text box created by me

Answer (score 1):

**Look not just facebook eventually if you would like to do this for twitter and linkedin, You should just keep in mind that you will never get the user's facebook/twitter/linkedin password.**

Now coming to your point particularly for facebook you should understand the `Graph Api` and what the `permissions` are?

Good news is that ,facebook returns you some of user data **(based on the permissions you ask for)**, in form of `json` that you may parse and save to your database. So you can parse this json response in your `servlet` or `java` code.

> But I would highly recommend to do some google and checkout facebook
>   login and graph API integration tutorials and hence you would be able to achieve the same on your particular frontend.

Comment: I extracted users information and displayed it on the HTML output but am not being able to store them in database any idea to do so?

Comment: You extracted information and displayed it on the HTML output, then why don't you handshake with `javascript` and use `getElementById` of `innerHtml` and then get parameters to your servlet.

Comment: @RamPrasad There is always an accept button and upvote if someone helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you can use this [Facebook login Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/)

or you can also use this one [Facebook login Tuts 2](http://onlinewebapplication.com/login-facebook-twitter-php/)